Panning during draw interaction breaks tracing of the draw interaction in OpenLayers
I have a draw interaction where I draw on an existing linestring feature in an Angular application. I start the draw interaction with tracing active to this linestring. When i pan after starting the draw interaction, the tracing breaks...
You can reproduce this issue on the OpenLayers example of tracing: Tracing example from openlayers

Start the tracing/draw interaction
Pan during the interaction
Notice that tracing is broken now

Relevant code from the openlayers example:
// this is where the drawn features go
const drawVector = new VectorLayer({
  source: new VectorSource(),
  style: {
    'stroke-color': 'rgba(100, 255, 0, 1)',
    'stroke-width': 2,
    'fill-color': 'rgba(100, 255, 0, 0.3)',
  },
});

const value = 'LineString';
const drawInteraction = new Draw({
  type: value,
  source: drawVector.getSource(),
  trace: true,
  traceSource: baseVector.getSource(),
});
map.addInteraction(drawInteraction);

I do notice the traceState_ = {active: false} when I inspect the Draw object after panning...
Is this by design and is it possible to have tracing active after panning by somehow updating this draw interaction after panning and re-enabling tracing?
ol version 9.1.0

There is probably a conflict of conditions between the interactions.  Try setting one up to work with a key pressed.

Thank you for answering. Do you mean a conflict between the snap-interaction and the draw-interaction? And I should try a setup where the snap-interaction only works with a key pressed down? (Trying to understand your workaround)

No, between Draw and DragPan, where both have a default of noModifierKeys.  For example adding condition: shiftKeyOnly, to the Draw interaction means that does not respond to pointer down unless the shift  key is down while the DragPan only repsonds when shift is not down.

You are correct, great suggestion! When I add the condition to the draw-interaction, panning does not break tracing! Now this does not solve the issue however: do you have any suggestion on how to fix the issue? In order to be able to pan around while drawing without any condition?

I also added the condition to panning and noticed the following: when I do not pan around (because I do not hold shift) and simply click, drag and release, the tracing is also broken... So the panning in itself could not be the cause of the issue.

Beware of creating new conflicts.  shiftKeyOnly on DragPan could conflict with defaults for DragZoom and freehandCondition for Draw.  Consider disabling those or setting to never.

I would say this is a flaw in OpenLayers, since both trace and map pane are native to OpenLayers and so should work together, not fight.
There is hackish workaround for this. Current status of tracing is stored in drawInteraction.traceState_ and is reset when map is panned. Workaround is to store this state at the start of the map pan and restore it when pan ends.
Code for doing that can look like this (tested):
var traceStateClone = null;

map.on('movestart', function() {
  if (drawInteraction.traceState_.active)
    traceStateClone = structuredClone(drawInteraction.traceState_);
  else {
    traceStateClone = null;
  }
});
map.on('moveend', function() {
  if (traceStateClone && !drawInteraction.traceState_.active) {
    drawInteraction.traceState_ = traceStateClone;
  }
});


Thank you for answering. This workaround fixed the issue! Typescript code will not compile however because traceState_ is a private property of a draw interaction: casting the draw interaction to 'any' fixes this issue for typescript. Many thanks!
